# replaceWith Function shows weird results

Tags: javascript, jquery, replacewith

I'm using replacewith function, though it's replacing the contents what I searched for, but makes up the html which is weired (the contents of html were correct before):
here's the snippet

```
var url = 'ControllerName//ActionName//' + Id;
var img = "<img style='width: 45px; height: 46px;' data-imageName='" + imageName 
          + "' src='javascript:window.location.href ='" + url + "'/>";
```

replacement code:

```
Panel.find(".heading1").find('.heading2').find('div:first')
     .replaceWith(function(){
                return (img);
            });
```

Upto this point it's working correctly, but the contents of the image tag (which I built above are changed like this:

```
<img style="width: 45px; height: 46px;" data-imagename="image.jpg" 
      src="javascript:window.location.href =" ControllerName="" 
      ActionName="" 72'="">
```

where 72 is the Id I passed above.
it should be like:

```
<img style="width: 45px; height: 46px;" data-imagename="image.jpg" 
        src="/ControllerName/ActionName?Id=72">
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just made the following changes and it worked:

```
var url = '/ControllerName/ActionName?Id=' + someId;
            var img = "<img style='width: 45px; height: 46px;' data-imageName='" + imageName + "' src='"  + url +  "'/>";
```

then instead of returning img in function, simply passed image

```
Panel.find(".heading1").find('.heading2').find('div:first').replaceWith(img);
```